# If $A$ has a Jordan form in $\mathbb{R}$, could it be that $A$ diagonalizes in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I was finding the Jordan form for a matrix $A \in M_{4}(\mathbb{R})$ given by:

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
\in M_{4}(\mathbb{R})
$$

whose characteristic polynomial is, $p_{A}(x)=(x-1)^{4}$ and minimal $m_{A}(x)=(x-1)^{2}$. And I had no problem in finding it's Jordan form:

$$
J=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ and, }
P=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ such that }
J=P^{-1}AP.
$$

But that's not the point of my question, since the problem came in the next section as they asked me if $J \in M_{4}(\mathbb{R})$ would change in any way (diagonalize) if instead of working in $M_{4}(\mathbb{R})$, we worked in $M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$. I suspect that $J$ won't change since the characteristic polynomial factorizes in $\mathbb{R}_{4}[x]$ as $p_{A}(x)=(x-1)^{4}$, and as $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}$ this implies that $p_{A}(x)$ will have the same factors in $\mathbb{C}_{4}[x]$ ($p_{A}(x)=(x-1)^{4}\in \mathbb{C}_{4}[x]$). So, I suspect that $J\in M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$ will also be

$$
J=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\in M_{4}(\mathbb{C})
$$

but i'm not sure. If so, where is my flaw? Is it true in general?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: $J$ is also the JNF over $\Bbb C$, so you are right.

Comment: Nice, but is this always true? Can this be generalized?

Comment: What is always true? Sometimes the result over $\Bbb C$ is different, of course.